# django's setting.py can't read utf-8 characters

Tags: django, django-settings

I have tried to give a value to my `MEDIA_ROOT` that  constain a word with an accent mark, but django doent accept it.
I have tried to unicode(utf-8) and encoding it with no positive results

The error that I get is: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file`
What can I do in order to make settings accept acent marks(ó,á,é,í,ú)

`SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file C:\Users\Meccha\Documents\django\project\settings.py on line 160, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

And in line 160 I have:`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(u'D:', u'INVESTIGACIÓN._P')`

Comment: Are you running Python-2.x?

Comment: yes, python 2.7 and django 1.11

Comment: then you need to prefix it with a `u`, so `u'foo/bar/qux'` insteaf of `'foo/bar/qux'`.

Comment: I get the same error 
`SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file settings.py  but no encoding declared`

Comment: add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top

Comment: It doesn´t working

Comment: This is how I was trying `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(u'D:', ' INVESTIGACIÓN_P')

Comment: But that are two strings, you need to prefix the second, since that is the one with unicode characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173902/discussion-between-mecha-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: I have also do that, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

In [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), there is a destinction between `str`, and `unicode`. `str` are **ASCII** strings, so these can contain *only* ASCII characters. On the other hand `unicode` strings can contain all unicode characters.

You can define a unicode string with the `u` prefix, this allows to write unicode characters like `u'\xf3'` to write a unicode string that contains the `Ã` character.

If you however want to write unicode strings as well, you need to specify the encoding of the file, in the header of the file. So then the **`settings.py`** file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals

import os

# ...
# (some other settings)
# ...

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join('D:', u' INVESTIGACIÓN_P')
```

So the top part specifies the encoding, and the latter has a `u` prefix to mark the string as a `unicode` string.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem as before

Comment: @Mecha: please post the full traceback.

Comment: @Mecha: it looks like you forgot to declare the encoding (see the part in boldface at the top!)

Comment: I have added it

Comment: @Mecha: what if you add an `from __future__ import unicode_literals`?

Comment: I get  `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'rawunicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uXXXX`. I going to delete the setting.py and create it again

Comment: @Mecha: I think you need to import the `from __future__` as well, since now it is interpreted as a bytestring, see updated answer.

Comment: It works, I create again my settings.py, and it works, without using from __future__, Thanks for thr help